# systemd modules load service failed load Kernel Modules ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, kernel, 17.10

Been looking for a solution to this for a while but can't seem to find a one.

```
systemctl --failed
```

UNIT                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed Load Kernel Modules

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.

```
systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
```

systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-01-02 19:55:24 EST; 37

Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)

Process: 5369 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, s

Main PID: 5369 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 02 19:55:24 qs-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Jan 02 19:55:24 qs-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main pr
Jan 02 19:55:24 qs-ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
Jan 02 19:55:24 qs-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit en
Jan 02 19:55:24 qs-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed

```
journalctl _PID=5369
```

-- Logs begin at Tue 2018-01-02 18:07:59 EST, end at Tue 2018-01-02 23:07:5
Jan 02 19:55:24 qs-ubuntu systemd-modules-load[5369]: Failed to find module

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there something not working at the user level?

Comment: everything seems to be working ok, but when I boot up i'm getting a 'FAILED' message; not sure the severity of it